# Django Tests Login/Logout

Tags: python, django

I'm testing a django app from this tutorial: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_admin/README.html

I've created a test from an example:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client, LiveServerTestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

####Lines removed for brevity####

class AdminTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['users.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_login(self):
        # Get login page
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')

        # Check response code
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log in' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log in' in response.content)

        # Log the user in
        self.client.login(username='XXX', password="XXX")

        # Check response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log out' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log out' in response.content)

    def test_logout(self):
        # Log in
        self.client.login(username='XXX', password="XXX")

        # Check response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log out' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log out' in response.content)

        # Log out
        self.client.logout()

        # Check response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log in' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log in' in response.content)
```

however when running `python manage.py test` I get this output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.FE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_logout (blog.tests.AdminTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\shenk\Documents\Programming\django_projects\djangogirls\blog\tests.py", line 80, in test_logout
self.assertTrue('Log out' in response.content)
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

======================================================================
FAIL: test_login (blog.tests.AdminTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\shenk\Documents\Programming\django_projects\djangogirls\blog\tests.py", line 56, in test_login
self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 302 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get this 302 response code aka redirect, how can I adjust these two tests to make them pass and be actually usable?

And a side-question... how can I print/examine the data in response.content as printing to STDOUT doesn't seem to work in a test?

I found a similar question where the person was testing logins, but the problem turned out to be that they were creating the user without a password, my user is already created via createsuperuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is I'm testing for a 200 code after logout, when it's redirecting me to another page.  To fix I should assertEquals for the 304 and then again for the 200 on the page redirected too.  This seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

While Logging in..

```
# Get login page
response = self.client.get('/admin/login/')

# Check response code
self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

When the URL is set to `'admin/'`, it always gets redirected to `admin/login/`. Thus returning `response.status_code` as 302 (Which means redirecting). This is true for Django Version 1.8.4